# Excel ISNUMBER(SEARCH) -- Mismatch

Tags: excel, excel-formula

My current situation is:

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Part I",B146)),"Part 1",IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Part II",B146)),"
Part 2"))
```

My problem is that I'm doing this for almost 890,000 rows of data so doing it by hand would be awful. There is text I'm sorting through to see how it is characterized.

The problem is "Part I" is literally contained within the "Part II" text, so everything that is supposed to return "Part 2" is returning "Part 1". Can anyone advise?

Thank you!

Comment: Flip the order, look for `Part II` first then `Part I`

Comment: @ScottCraner right before I read this that is EXACTLY what I did -- success!! Thank you!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just like @Scott Craner said -- flipping the order works. Search for "Part II" first.

Awesome, thank you!